# Create single executable file from directory

Tags: make, gcc

I'm looking to create a single executable file from a directory, to make a 'standalone' app.

So say my directory structure is:

```
-app
  --assets
  --bin
  --views
  runme
  go.sh
```

and within `go.sh` I have a line to simply run `runme`:

```
./runme --myswitch
```

So when you double click the `executable` file, it will run `go.sh`, and the rest of the app will go and do its work.

I've looked into using `gcc`, but this seems specific to C apps? Not just running a script.

---

Specifically, this is trying to make a standalone Xulrunner application. The docs just suggest create a `.tar.bz2` file, rather than a `.exe` style file, which is what I'm looking for.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/XULRunner/Deploying_XULRunner_1.8

Comment: Show the code of app or at least tell us which programming language is used.

Comment: @enedil updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `.tar.bz2` is just for distribution. It must be unpacked for your app to execute.

What you probably want to do is create a `.desktop` file for your thing see http://linuxcritic.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/anatomy-of-a-desktop-file/.

Also, Firefox/Iceweasel is an XULRunner application, so check what it does and copy it.

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it is preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.